# how to add captions to a picture programatically

Tags: vb.net, image

How I Can add some text in pictures automatically?

-- I have a bunch of products and i want to add descriptions and price below of image . And I want to do this job by writing some line of code in vb.net

Because i have more than 2000 images which names is incremental numbers.

Here is a sample image: 
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkoe9.jpg)

Like this image.

Comment: do u want to add the texts in the image? i suggest u to use a database instead for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use(if u don't wanna use a database) a [RichTextBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use this code to add image to the RichTextBox:

```
   'add openfiledial to add image to RichTextBox
    img = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Clipboard.SetImage(img)
    Richtextbox1.Paste()
   'add some text beneath your image.
```

Save the richTextBox to file :

```
   Private sub Btn_save_click

   'add a saveFileDialogBox
   SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog

   Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_DialogResultOk
   richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFiledialog1.FileName, _
        RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
```

This is one solution but there are other solutions.Comment if u need them

**To load text from file**

```
  Richtextbox1.text=file.readalllines(use file location here/openfiledialog.filename)
```

**USING A DATABASE IS THE PERFECT ANSWER**

As u said, u have a text file containg the prices...I suggest u to use either MSSQL/ACCESS DATABASE/MYSQL

Now to generate records depending on the text file..Use this(load the textfile in the rtb first)

```
  Dim con as new SqlConnection(Your connectionstring here)
  Con.open
  Dim cmd as new sqlcommand("Insert into [table name-remove brackets if   required](columnname) values("@price")",con)
  Dim i as integer
  For each line in RichTextbox1.Lines
  cmd.parameters.add("@price", sqldbtype.varchar).value=Richtxtbox1.lines(i).text
  cmd.executenonquery
  Next
  Con.close
```

Comment: yeah..then u can load the text file in the rich textbox...i again say, using a database will be best idea

Comment: I have a text file which contains prices of products

--> Each line is a price for one product , and every product have a unique id which is  in image name e.g: 1690 

And in this program i want to define 'starting id' and 'ending id' then the program automatically read prices in text line and put theme in images